# How to rearrange an array in such a way that each element is greater/smaller than its neighbours

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

For example, if the numbers are:

```
30, 12, 49, 6, 10, 50, 13
```

The array will be:

```
[10, 6, 30, 12, 49, 13, 50]
```

As you can see:

- 6 is smaller than both 10 and 30 and
- 49 is greater than 12 and 13 and so on.

The numbers are all different and real. I need the most efficient algorithm.

Comment: You need all the solutions or just the first one?

Comment: It would be great if the algorithm could generate all the solutions. but the algorithm must be the most time-efficient one.

Comment: I feel that calculating "all solutions" might tend to have `O(n!)` complexity...

Comment: the best solution is not here check this out [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777762/aranging-integers-in-a-specific-order)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be done in O(n):

1. Find median in O(n) (description is available in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm)
2. Put every element larger than the median on odd places and every smaller element - on even places

Of course, this assumes that all elements are distinct, otherwise sometimes it will fail.

Comment: wait a minute! we can't find the median in O(n) by selection, we can just find the median of medians, which is not necessarily the median. it is not in the 50%, just more than 30% and less than 70% of the length of array!

Comment: @Peggy: please, read the whole Wikipedia article, even if we can consistently select pivot with smallest part 30%, this is enough for quickselect to be O(n) in worst case.

Comment: yes, you are right. after finding the medians of median, we can again find the median by finding (n/2)th smallest element. (finding kth smallest element iin O(n)). Sorry

Answer (score 14):

Assuming the numbers are all distinct, the easiest way is probably to sort the numbers then interleave the first and second halves of the sorted list. This will guarantee the high/low/high/low/high/low/.... pattern that you need.

This algorithm is `O(n log n)` which should be efficient enough for most purposes, and may benefit from optimised sorting routines in your standard library.

If the numbers are not distinct, then it is possible that there is no solution (e.g. if the numbers are all equal)

Comment: I think that will be the best way to do that

Comment: I think this answer isn't quite correct. If the numbers were 1, 2, 2, 3
you would have 1 2 2 3 as the answer? when you could have 2 1 3 2

Comment: How does it interleave 1 2 2 3, I suppose it would go 2 1 2 3

Comment: [2 3] is one half and [1 2] is another half. so [2 1 3 2] is actually interleaving the two halves. And just for the record, @mikera said that his solution is for distinct numbers...

Comment: Depends which half you put first. I'll try come up with a counter example.

Comment: I haven't been able to find a proper counter example. There is a slight edge case to consider:
1 2 2 -> [1] [2 2] -> 2 1 2
while using the same logic 1 1 2 -> [1] [1 2] -> 1 1 2

Comment: It is unnecessary to completely sort. Using quick select (median of medians) algorithm, you can find the median element in `O(n)` and partition the array into smalls and larges which you can then interleave, `O(n)`. Yes, for practical purposes a fast `O(n log(n))` can be better than a slow `O(n)`.

Comment: @A Webb - great point, I agree the full sort is not needed. Though if your language has a decent sort implementation (likely?) it will probably beat a hand-rolled median-partitioning implementation and be a lot simpler/less error prone to use. YMMV.

Comment: @mikera there is no way a sorting algorithm will beat a median finder

Comment: @aaronman - clearly not if both are perfectly optimised. But that wasn't my claim: I was observing that a highly optimised sorting algorithm (as found in many language implementations) will probably beat a naive hand-rolled median finder (of the type that an average developer would probably write)

Comment: @mikera for one c++ has an nth element finder and two you have a low opinion of the avg developer

Answer (score 2):

Someone posted this question as a dupe to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777762/aranging-integers-in-a-specific-order/17777949#17777949) but the solution over there is better than the accepted solution here so I figured I'd post it here.

Basically the key is for every three numbers where it has to hold that `a < b > c` you look at the sequence and swap the biggest number into the center. Then you increment by 2 to get to the next sequence like `a < b > c` and do the same thing.

Technically the solution still runs in O(n) like the accepted solution, but it is a better O(n) and it is much simpler because the median of medians algo is tricky to implement. Hopefully anyone who favorited this problem will at least see this solution, I can post the code if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too knowledgeable about complexity, but here's my idea.

```
For even length lists:

(For our odd length example, 
 put 30 aside to make the list even) 

1. Split the list into chunks of 2    => [[12,49],[6,10],[50,13]]
2. Sort each chunk                    => [[12,49],[6,10],[13,50]]
3. Reverse-sort the chunks by 
   comparing the last element of 
   one to the first element of 
   the second                         => [[12,49],[13,50],[6,10]]

For odd length lists:
4. Place the removed first element in 
   the first appropriate position     => [30,12,49,13,50,6,10]
```

Haskell code:

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)

rearrange :: [Int] -> [Int]
rearrange xs
  | even (length xs) = rearrangeEven xs
  | null (drop 1 xs) = xs
  | otherwise        = place (head xs) (rearrangeEven (tail xs))
 where place x (y1:y2:ys) 
         | (x < y1 && y1 > y2) || (x > y1 && y1 < y2) = (x:y1:y2:ys)
         | otherwise                                  = place' x (y1:y2:ys)
       place' x (y1:y2:ys) 
         | (x < y1 && x < y2) || (x > y1 && x > y2) = (y1:x:y2:ys)
         | otherwise                                = y1 : (place' x (y2:ys))
       rearrangeEven = concat 
                     . sortBy (\a b -> compare (head b) (last a)) 
                     . map sort
                     . chunksOf 2
```

Output:

```
*Main> rearrange [30,12,49,6,10,50,13]
[30,12,49,13,50,6,10]

*Main> rearrange [1,2,3,4]
[3,4,1,2]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. For example, for `[3,4,0,1,2]` it returns `[1,0,2,4,3]` which is not valid since the `2` is greater than the `0` but less than the `4`. A valid solution in this case would be e.g. `[0,4,1,3,2]`. Found using [this small test harness I wrote using QuickCheck](http://hpaste.org/88619).

Comment: @hammar Here's something interesting: I changed one line, like this: `prop_correct (Distinct xs) = odd (length xs) || valid (rearrange xs)` and I got this: `+++ OK, passed 100 tests.`