# Complexity of a sortBy in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, complexity-theory, big-o

I came up with an [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748130/how-to-rearrange-an-array-in-such-a-way-that-each-element-is-either-greater-or-s/16759488#16759488) to solve another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748130/how-to-rearrange-an-array-in-such-a-way-that-each-element-is-either-greater-or-s) and am hoping for some help with determining the function's complexity since I'm not too knowledgeable about that. Would I be correct in guessing that "unsorting" each of the chunks would be `O (n * log 2)` ? And then what would be the complexity of the sortBy function that compares the last of one chunk to the head of another? My guess is that that function would only compare pairs and not require finding one chunk's order in terms of the total list. Also, would Haskell offer different complexity because of a lazy optimization of the overall function? Thanks, in advance!

```
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf)
import Data.List (sortBy)

rearrange :: [Int] -> [Int]
rearrange = concat 
          . sortBy (\a b -> compare (last a) (head b)) 
          . map (sortBy (\a b -> compare b a)) 
          . chunksOf 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Well step by step

1. `chunksOf 2` must iterate through the whole list so `O(n)` and we  half the length of the list. However, since constant multiples don't affect complexity we can ignore this.
2. `map (sortBy...` iterates through the whole list `O(n)` doing a constant time operation* `O(1)`=`O(1*n)` = `O(n)`
3. `sortBy` with a constant time comparison* is `O( n * log n)`
4. `concat` which is `O(n)`

So in total `O(n + n + n log n + n)` = `O ((3 + log n) * n)` = `O(n log n)`

*Since the lists are guarenteed to be of length 2 or less, we can say that operations like sorting and accessing the last element are `O(2 * log 2)` and `O(2)` respectively, which are both constant time, `O(1)`

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the parts in isolation (let `n` be the length of the list argument):

- `chunksOf 2` is `O(n)`, resulting in a list of length `` (n+1) `quot` 2 ``.
- `map (sortBy ...)`: Since all lists that are passed to `sortBy ...` have length `<= 2`, each of those sorts is `O(1)`, and thus the entire `map` is `O(n)` again.
- `sortBy (\a b -> compare (last a) (head b))`: The comparison is always `O(1)`, since the lists whose `last` element is taken are of bounded length (`<= 2`), thus the entire `sortBy` operation is `O(n*log n)`
- `concat` is `O(n)` again.

So overall, we have `O(n*log n)`.

Note, however, that

```
cmp = \a b -> compare (last a) (head b)
```

is an inconsistent comparison, for two lists `a` and `b` (say `[30,10]` and `[25,15]`), you can have

```
cmp a b == cmp b a = LT
```

I'm not sure that your algorithm always works.

After looking at the implementation of `sortBy` and tracing the sort a bit in my head, I think that for the given purpose, it works (provided the list elements are distinct) and the inconsistent comparison does no harm. For some sorting algorithms, an inconsistent comparison might cause the sorting to loop, but for merge sort variants, that should not occur.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm not if I understand the example of where the algorithm might fail. Can you show more concretely an example where it fails?  I think [30,10,25,15] would satisfy that question's requirement.

Comment: I didn't say it would fail for some examples, I said I'm not sure that it always works (since the comparison is inconsistent, some sorting algorithms could even loop). But, having looked at the source and traced it a bit in my head, I think it will always (well, if all list elements are distinct) work. I'm still not _sure_, though.