# Aranging integers in a specific order

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a set of  distinct unsorted integers s1, s2, .., sn how do you arrange integers such that s1 < s2 > s3 < s4...

I know this can be solved by looking at the array from left to right and  if the condition is not satisfied swapping those two elements gives the right answer. Can someone explain me why this algorithm works.

Comment: do you mean s1<s2>s3<s4>s5? or s1<s2<s3<s4?

Comment: What exactly is your C++ question?

Comment: What exactly is your algorithm?

Comment: @Iuser2580076 meant s1<s2>s3<s4>s5

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748130/how-to-rearrange-an-array-in-such-a-way-that-each-element-is-greater-smaller-tha

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, he is implying that there is a different way(slightly better) to solve it but doesn't understand why it works

Comment: @user2605095 if you don't mind me asking where did you find this problem, were you asked it in an interview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given any three successive numbers in the array, there are four possible relationships:

```
a < b < c
a < b > c
a > b < c
a > b > c
```

In the first case we know that a < c. Since the first condition is met, we can swap b and c to meet the second condition, and the first condition is still met.

In the second case, both conditions are already met.

In the third case, we have to swap a and b to give b < a ? c. But we already know that b < c, so if a < c then swapping to meet that second condition doesn't invalidate the first condition.

In the last case we know that a > c, so swapping a and b to meet the first condition maintains the validity of the second condition.

Now, you add a fourth number to the sequence. You have:

```
a < b > c ? d
```

If c < d then there's no need to change anything. But if we have to swap c and d, the prior condition is still met. Because if b > c and c > d, then we know that b > d. So swapping c and d gives us b > d < c.

You can use similar reasoning when you add the fifth number. You have `a < b > c < d ? e`. If d > e, then there's no need to change anything. If d < e, then by definition c < e as well, so swapping maintains the prior condition.

Pseudo code that implements the algorithm:

```
for i = 0 to n-2
    if i is even
        if (a[i] > a[i+1])
            swap(a[i], a[i+1])
        end if
    else
        if (a[i] < a[i+1])
            swap(a[i], a[i+1])
    end
```

Comment: It's funny the suggested dupe is sort of a dupe, but the accepted solution is not as good as this one, and the solution with 13 upvotes is O(nlogn)

Comment: @aaronman What's the complexity for this algorithm to solve `3,2,1,1,1,1,4,5` ?

Comment: @groovy: The algorithm that the OP describes is O(n). The sequence you show does not meet the requirements. The OP said, "distinct unsorted integers." Your example has duplicate values.

Comment: @groovy I noticed that this solution is better than the ones in the dupe you marked too

Comment: @aaronman yes, it does seem so! Although I still find the odd/even array indexes idea inspiring in terms of thinking out of the box.

Comment: @groovy you mean the accepted solution right, I just like this one because it's so simple and requires you noticing some clever stuff

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to the suggested solution in java.

```
public static int [] alternatingList(int [] list) {
    int first, second,third;
    for (int i = 0;i < list.length-2;i+=2) {
        first = list[i];
        second = list[i+1];
        third = list[i+2];
        if (first > second && first > third) {
            list[i+1] = first;
            list[i] = second;
        }
        else if (third> first && third > second) {
            list[i+1] = third;
            list[i+2] = second;
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

In this code since all the numbers are distinct there will always be a bigger number to put into the "peaks". Swapping the numbers will not change the consistency of the last part you did because the number you swap out will always be smaller than the one you put into the new peak.

**Keep in mind this code doesn't handle some edge cases like even length lists and lists smaller than three, I wrote it pretty fast :), I only wrote the code to illustrate the concept of the solution**

In addition this solution is better than the one in the proposed dupe because it makes one pass. The solution in the dupe uses the hoare's selection algorithm which is n but requires multiple decreasing in size passes on the list, also it needs to make another n pass on the list after using Hoare's (or the median of medians).

**More mathematical proof:**
For every three consecutive numbers `a,b,c` there are three options

```
a > b && a > c
b > c && b > a
c > a && c > b
```

In the first case you switch `a` into the middle because it's the largest, second case do nothing (largest is already in the middle) and 3rd case 'c` goes to the middle.

now you have `a < b > c d e` where for now d and e are unknown. Now the new `a,b,c` are `c,d,e` and you do the same operation this is guaranteed not to mess up the order since `c` will only be changed if it is larger than `d` and `e` thus the number moved into `c`'s spot will be smaller than `b` and not break the ordering, this can continue infinitely clearly with the order never breaking.

Comment: I don't think he was asking for the code. He was asking for why it works.

Comment: @JimMischel I wrote the code so I could understand why it works, but it looks like you already figured it out, I figured why not post it